# select the Rows which contains same text in last two columns of data frame in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, if-statement

I have a data frame which looks below

```
import pandas as pd

k={'ID':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'m1':['jj','nn','jj','nn','nn','nn'],
   'm2':['jj','nn','nn','jj','jj','jj'],
   'm3':['jj','','nn','jj','jj','jj'],
   'm4':['nn','','nn','jj','jj','jj'],
   'm5':['nn','','','jj','jj','nn'],
   'm6':['','','','jj','jj','nn']}

df=pd.DataFrame(data=k)

ID  m1  m2  m3  m4  m5  m6
1   jj  jj  jj  nn  nn  
2   nn  nn              
3   jj  nn  nn  nn      
4   nn  jj  jj  jj  jj  jj
5   nn  jj  jj  jj  jj  jj
6   nn  jj  jj  jj  nn  nn
```

we have to select the ID which contains 'nn' in  last two columns **but the last column for each row(ID) is different**

### I want the result as follows

```
ID  last1   last2   last two columns are nn
1   nn       nn         yes
2   nn       nn         yes
3   nn       nn         yes
6   nn       nn         yes
```

Comment: You probably mean df=pd.DataFrame(index=k.pop("ID"), data=k)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC `melt` with `groupby` then pick the `tail` 2

```
s=df.melt('ID').loc[lambda x : x.value!=''].groupby('ID').tail(2)
s['variable']=s.groupby('ID').cumcount()
s=s.pivot(*s.columns)
s
Out[86]: 
variable   0   1
ID              
1         nn  nn
2         nn  nn
3         nn  nn
4         jj  jj
5         jj  jj
6         nn  nn
```

After we get the df like above, we can pick it up

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```py
def double_nn_filter(row):
    row[row == ''] = None
    return row.dropna().tail(2).eq("nn").all()


df.apply(double_nn_filter, axis=1)
```

result:

```
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
6     True
```